# How to fix the error: Pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to put togheter several JSON files into one CSV file and put this file in a folder in my computer, but I got the following error:

pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 8, saw 2

My code so far:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import os.path

path = '/mypath/*.json'
files = glob(path)


 data = pd.concat((pd.read_json(file, error_bad_lines=False)) for file in files)

 data.to_csv(os.path.join('/path where I want to put the csv file','yourfilename.csv'))
```

This is the JSON file structure:

```
{
"data":[
  {
     "attachments":"3_1630878910203273218",
     "id":"1630878914296913926"
  },
  {
     "attachments":"4839577767895768",
     "id":"18945865497657868"
  }
     ],
"includes":{
  "media":[
     {
        "media_key":"3_1630878910203273218",
        "type":"photo",
        "url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FqILumJXoAIOzy4.jpg"
     }
   ]
 },
"meta":{
  "newest_id":"1630878914296913926",
  "oldest_id":"1627974617309519873",
  "result_count":38
    }
   }
```

What I expect is a csv file that contains only the "data" part of
my JSON file:

| attachments | id |
| --- | --- |
| 3_1630878910203273218 | 1630878914296913926 |
| 4839577767895768 | 18945865497657868 |

I don't know where is my error

Comment: Why are you using [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to parse *JSON* files ? Also, can you make a minimal reproducible example, include it to your question *as text* and show the exact matching expected output ?

Comment: Oops I did a mistake I edited the question. Which kind of example? Sorry I'm new in the plataform. I have a folder in my computer that contains all the json files, it's located in '/mypath/

Comment: After correcting the code I have this error: ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Comment: No worries, can you share an example (*a few lines*) of your *JSON* files and add the expected output ?

Comment: I have included a small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) :

```
path = '/mypath/*.json'
files = glob(path)
​
list_dfs = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        list_dfs.append(pd.json_normalize(json.load(f)['data']))
​
data = pd.concat(list_dfs, ignore_index=True)
​
data.to_csv(os.path.join('/path where I want to put the csv file', 'yourfilename.csv'))
```

Output :

```
print(data)

             attachments                   id
0  3_1630878910203273218  1630878914296913926
1       4839577767895768    18945865497657868
```

Comment: That is correct, thank you! Perhaps you know how  modify the code to consider only "attachments" and "id" in case it has more elements in "date".

Comment: Sure, use `data = pd.concat(list_dfs, ignore_index=True)[["attachments", "id"]]`.

Comment: There is a way to remove the index  0 and 1 ?

Comment: Yes, use `data.to_csv(...'yourfilename.csv'), index=False)`.